# How have getters and setters for every property of class?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, magic-methods

Can't we use php magic getter setter for doctrine2 entity classes instead of making getter setter for every property of class?

This is my entity class written for doctrine2 to map with table in database.

```
    <?php
namespace Entities;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class blogs
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=11)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1024, nullable=true)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=512, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $blog_data;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entities\likes", mappedBy="blogs")
     */
    private $likeses;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entities\share", mappedBy="blogs")
     */
    private $shares;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entities\comments", mappedBy="blogs")
     */
    private $commentses;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entities\ilook_user", inversedBy="blogses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="blog_writer_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $ilook_user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entities\blog_categories", inversedBy="blogses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="blog_categories_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $blog_categories;

    public function setId($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function setUrl($url){
        $this->url=$url;
    }
    public function getUrl(){
        return $this->url;
    }
    public function setTitle($title){
        $this->title = $title;
    }
    public function getTitle(){
        return $this->title;
    }
    public function setBlog_data($blog_data){
        $this->blog_data = $blog_data;
    }
    public function getBlog_data(){
        return $this->blog_data;
    }
    public function setLikeses($likeses){
        $this->likeses=$likeses;
    }
    public function getLikeses(){
        return $this->likeses;
    }
    public function setShares($shares){
        $this->shares = $shares;
    }
    public function getShares(){
        return $this->shares;
    }
    public function setCommentses($commentses){
        $this->commentses = $commentses;
    }
    public function getCommentses(){
        return $this->commentses;
    }
    public function setIlook_user($ilook_user){
        $this->ilook_user = $ilook_user;
    }
    public function getIlook_user(){
        return $this->ilook_user;
    }
    public function setBlog_categories($blog_categories){
        $this->blog_categories = $blog_categories;
    }
    public function getBlog_categories(){
        return $this->blog_categories;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

See this example with the magics methods `__set` and `__get`:

```
<?php
class PropertyTest
{
    private $a, $b;

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        echo "Set '$name' to '$value'\n";
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
    public function __get($name)
    {
        echo "Get $name \n";
        return $this->$name;
    }
}
echo "<pre>\n";
$obj = new PropertyTest;
$obj->a = 1;
echo $obj->a . "\n\n";

echo "<pre>\n";
$obj = new PropertyTest;
$obj->b = "Hello";
echo $obj->b . "\n\n";

?>
```

You can read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

Edit with other example using the magic method `__call`:

```
<?php
class Called {
    private $Id, $Name;

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $action = substr($name, 0, 3);
        $field = substr($name, 3);

        if($action == 'set') {
            $this->$field = $arguments[0];
        }       

        if($action == 'get') {
            return $this->$field;
        }       
    }
}

$obj = new Called();
$obj->setId(4);
echo "<br/>\n";
echo $obj->getId();

echo "<br/>\n";

$obj->setName('Peter');
echo "<br/>\n";
echo $obj->getName();

?>
```

you can read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Comment: How is that a getter and a setter?

Comment: @dan-klasson I don't understand you, can you explain your comment please

Comment: for those of us that are confused by classes, but get functions, can you write it as functions, like setter (sets a var), and verifier (returns T/F)

Comment: Your second example is using getters and setters (that wasn't there when i first made my comment). Your first one is just setting class variables. You might as well set the class variables to public.